# Converting integer to a character pointer in c++ and then appending it to another chacter pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following code for converting the integer(a score) into the character and then appending it with the player's name (player1). It gets displayed after that. It is a part of a bigger project :

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char* convertIntTochar(int number)
{
    char t[3];
    t[0] = 0;
    t[1] = 0;
    t[2] = '\0';

    int i = 0;
    for(; number != 0; i++)
    {
        t[i] = ((number%10) + 48);
        number/=10;
    }

    if(i == 2)
    {
        char temp = t[0];
        t[0] = t[1];
        t[1] = temp; 
    }
    else
        t[i] = '\0';
    char *ans = t;
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    char str11[] = "Player1: ";
    char *str1 = str11;
    char *str2 = convertIntTochar(11);
    strcat(str1 , str2);

    while(*str1)
    {
        cout<<*(str1++);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles correctly but when I run it , it shows the following error :

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x50)[0x9b3390]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0xe233a)[0x9b333a]
./a.out[0x80487ff]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x8e7bd6]
./a.out[0x8048621]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-00134000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2887608    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.11.1.so
00134000-00135000 r--p 00023000 08:06 2887608    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.11.1.so
00135000-00136000 rw-p 00024000 08:06 2887608    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.11.1.so
004b9000-004d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2887597    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
004d4000-004d5000 r--p 0001a000 08:06 2887597    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
004d5000-004d6000 rw-p 0001b000 08:06 2887597    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
0077d000-00866000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2756275    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
00866000-00867000 ---p 000e9000 08:06 2756275    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
00867000-0086b000 r--p 000e9000 08:06 2756275    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
0086b000-0086c000 rw-p 000ed000 08:06 2756275    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
0086c000-00873000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
008d1000-00a24000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2887604    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
00a24000-00a25000 ---p 00153000 08:06 2887604    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
00a25000-00a27000 r--p 00153000 08:06 2887604    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
00a27000-00a28000 rw-p 00155000 08:06 2887604    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
00a28000-00a2b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00a3b000-00a58000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2883667    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00a58000-00a59000 r--p 0001c000 08:06 2883667    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00a59000-00a5a000 rw-p 0001d000 08:06 2883667    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00b74000-00b75000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4719693    /home/dhruv/Desktop/a.out
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:06 4719693    /home/dhruv/Desktop/a.out
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:06 4719693    /home/dhruv/Desktop/a.out
08b67000-08b88000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b77f7000-b77f9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b780d000-b7810000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bfd2a000-bfd3f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Player1: "�ӿ�XMAborted
```

What is the reason for this? How can it be rectified. I have already put the null termination character in the convertIntTochar function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   char str11[] = "Player1: ";
```

This is the problem. There is not enough room for string concatenation. Try this:

```
   char str11[100] = "Player1: ";
```

Better yet, use `std::string` instead of C-like `char*`. Smallest possible changes that fix string problems are these (because there exist `using namespace std` then `std::` part in `std::string` can be left out, but I just prefer to leave it in):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // instead of <string.h>
using namespace std;

std::string convertIntTochar(int number)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "Player1: ";
    std::string str2 = convertIntTochar(11);
    str1 += str2;

    cout << str1;

    // Or even more effective, just one line of code:
    cout << "Player1: " << convertIntTochar(11);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me about std::string? I am kinda new to the language

Comment: Why play cheap. There are plenty of more bytes where these came from.

Answer (score 6):

Many problems here...

1. convertIntTochar works for 2 digit numbers only. No checks are done.
2. `char t[3]` defined in convertIntTochar is a local variable, you can't return a pointer to it and use this pointer outside convertIntTochar.
3. `strcat(str1 , str2);` appends to an array that is already full (str11) so you overwrite the stack.

Just switch to std::strings, it will be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::strings and std::ostringstreams, it's much simpler.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
std::ostringstream player_score_stream;
player_score_stream << "Player1: " << score_as_an_integer;
std::string player_score(player_score_stream.str());
std::cout << player_score;
```

and if you want a read-only C string, use player_score.c_str(), that returns a const char *

Answer (score 0):

To convert int to `char *` see if you can use `itoa` with your compiler.
If it is not supported you can find its implemenation to do what you want.
That is if you have to do it using C-strings